# how to change color when clicked button for particular event in list view and hold the button color even if we closed and return back to the button

Tags: java, android

here I have added my invitation(event) fragment code here I want to change the color of the button when I clicked particular button for particular event in listview

```
 public class InvitationFragment extends Fragment {
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        ViewGroup container;
        Bundle savedInstanceState;
        private List<String> eventName = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<Long> eventId = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> eventPlace = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<EventMO> eventMOs = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<Long> eventUserId = new ArrayList<>();
        private Context context;
        private UserOccasions userOccasions;
        private UserDelegate userDelegate = new UserDelegate();
        private EventDelegates eventDelegates = new EventDelegates();
        private Gson gson = new Gson();
        private ProgressDialog prgDialog;
        private UserMO userMO;
        private CheckBox invitationCheckBox;
        private ListView occasionView;
        private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
        private View view;
        private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;


        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            Log.d("onOptionsItemSelected", "yes");

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_cancel_event:
                    displayInvitationList();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

        }

        public void displayInvitationList() {

            int itemCount = occasionView.getCheckedItemCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= itemCount; i++) {
                if (userOccasions.getCheckedInvitationCount() != null) {
                    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                   // eventUserId = userOccasions.getCheckedInvitationCount();
                   // db.delete("user_relation", "EVENT_USER_ID" + " = ?", new String[]{Long.toString(eventUserId)});
                    db.close();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
                savedInstanceState) {
            this.inflater = inflater;
            this.container = container;
            this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.invitation_tab, container, false);
            context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            eventId.clear();
            eventName.clear();
            eventPlace.clear();
            // Set Progress Dialog Text
            prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            // Set Cancelable as False
            prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
            prgDialog.show();


            DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            userMO = dbHelper.getRingeeUserData(1);
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    return eventDelegates.getAllEventForUser(userMO, context);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String eventLists) {
                    if (eventLists != "null") {
                        eventMOs = gson.fromJson(eventLists, new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                        }.getType());
                        Toast.makeText(context, "total items of eventMo" + eventMOs.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        for (EventMO eventMO : eventMOs) {
                            eventName.add(eventMO.getText());
                            eventId.add(eventMO.getEventId());
                            eventPlace.add(eventMO.getPlace());
                        }

                        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                        //long totalInsertion = dbHelper.insertUserRelationTable(userMOs);
                        prgDialog.dismiss();
                        //Toast.makeText(context, "total userMos size " + userMOs.size() + "total db insertion size " + totalInsertion, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        occasionView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.invitation_list_view);
                        userOccasions = new UserOccasions();
                        occasionView.setAdapter(userOccasions);
                        occasionView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
                        occasionView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                        occasionView.setOnItemClickListener(occasionView.getOnItemClickListener());
                    }
                }
            }.execute(null, null, null);
            return view;
        }


        private class UserOccasions extends BaseAdapter {
            LayoutInflater mInflater;
            TextView eventNameTxtV, eventPlaceTxtV;
            private ArrayList<EventMO> checkedInvitationItems;
            private Object invitationTag;

            UserOccasions() {
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                this.checkedInvitationItems = new ArrayList<EventMO>();
            }


            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return eventMOs.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            // show list values name and mobile number in contact page
            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                if (null == convertView) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.invitation, null);
                }
                eventNameTxtV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitationTitle);
                eventPlaceTxtV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitationPlace);
                eventNameTxtV.setText(eventMOs.get(position).getText());
                eventPlaceTxtV.setText(eventMOs.get(position).getPlace());
                // intializing variables
                final EventMO eventMO = eventMOs.get(position);
                convertView.setTag(position);
                View v = convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_single);

                final LinearLayout eventLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_single);
                invitationCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitationCheckBox);
                Button yesBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
                Button noBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.noButton);
                Button maybeBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMayBe);

                final LinearLayout responseLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hidden);

                invitationCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                 boolean isChecked) {

                        if (isChecked) {

                            checkedInvitationItems.add((EventMO) eventMO);
                        } else {

                            checkedInvitationItems.remove((EventMO) eventMO);
                        }

                    }

                });

                //Based on the user click, response will be stored
                yesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {



                        responseLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //If user clicks yes button in invitation response layout,response would be stored as 1 for event user
                        final int response = 1;
                        final long eventId = eventMOs.get(position).getEventId();
                        userMO.setIsAttending(response);

                        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                                return userDelegate.updateEventUserRelationShipMapping(userMO, eventId);

                            }

                        }.execute(null, null, null);

                    }

                });
                noBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        responseLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //If user clicks no button in invitation response layout,response would be stored as 0 for event user
                        final int response = 0;
                        final long eventId = eventMOs.get(position).getEventId();
                        userMO.setIsAttending(response);

                        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                                return userDelegate.updateEventUserRelationShipMapping(userMO, eventId);

                            }

                        }.execute(null, null, null);
                    }
                });
                maybeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        responseLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //If user clicks maybe button in invitation response layout,response would be stored as  for event user
                        final int response = 2;
                        userMO.setIsAttending(response);
                        final long eventId = eventMOs.get(position).getEventId();

                        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                                return userDelegate.updateEventUserRelationShipMapping(userMO, eventId);

                            }

                        }.execute(null, null, null);
                    }
                });


                eventLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        switch (v.getId()) {
                            case R.id.invitation_single:
                                responseLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;
                        }
                    }


                });


                return convertView;
            }

            public ArrayList<EventMO> getCheckedInvitationCount() {
                return this.checkedInvitationItems;
            }


        }
    }
```

here I have tried the following code for change the colour of the button when the button clicked but it will not hold the colour when we go back and return back to the button and it will work for all events

```
yesBtn.setbackgroundColor(color.Yellow);
noBtn.setbackgroundColor(color.blue);
maybeBtn.setbackgroundColor(color.blue);
```

the above mentioned code is under `yesBtn.oncliclListener()` method.

Comment: store the state of button in Shared Preferences.

Comment: can u please tell me how to use shared preference here because I am new to android

Comment: here is the link for understanding Shared Preferences - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
yesBtn.setBackgroundColor(getColor(android.R.color.black));
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: here my problem is when I go to back and return back to this button it shows as it normal color not changed

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,
Create res/color/button_dark_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:color="#000000" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:color="#000000" /> <!-- focused -->
 <item android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

In layout xml

```
<Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="you text"
   android:textColor="@color/button_dark_text" />
```

Comment: thanks for your reply i will try this and tell u later weather its worked or not

Comment: in res am i want to create color coz already i have color.xml nder values. in there we defined only color names